# $n$-dimensional surface in $\mathbf{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

If $n$-dimensional surface in $\mathbf{R}^n$ is an open subset of $\mathbf{R}^n$ what is then a $0$-dimensional surface in $\mathbf{R}^n$ ?

**EDIT**[image]

Comment: Surface is a word usually reserved for referring to a 2-dimensional manifold. What do you mean by a surface in this context?

Comment: @DavidSheard Please see my edit.

Comment: You should add the definition of *surface*.

Comment: @PaulFrost I cannot find it. I can only put [here](http://31.42.184.140/main/1160000/0d9c8a29efbbb762e3b32b9dddd08423/Jaroslav%20Luke%C5%A1%2C%20Jan%20Mal%C3%BD%20-%20Measure%20and%20integral-Matfyz%20press%20%282005%29.pdf) a copy of that book.

Comment: What they call an "$n$-dimensional surface" is usually called an $n$-dimensional **manifold**. It's very unfortunate that they misuse it.

Comment: If you have access to the full pdf I think the definition is given on p166

Comment: There are many different kinds of topological dimension, including the small inductive dimension, the large inductive dimension, the covering dimension, and others.

Answer (score 3):

As is stated in your edit, a 0-dimensional surface consists of a countable set of isolated points, ie a subset $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ which is either finite or in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$, and such that for any point there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that the distance to any other point in $S$ is greater than $\varepsilon$. An example would be $S=\mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{R}$. A non-example would be $S=\{1/n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{0\}\subset \mathbb{R}$, since given any $\varepsilon>0$, there is some sufficiently large $n$ such that $1/n<\varepsilon$, so 0 is not an isolated point.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I do not know the reason why such $\varepsilon$ should exist for the surface to be $0$-dimensional.

Comment: Your edit made clear that in this context the word "surface" is being used loosely to mean any dimension of manifold, but to precisely answer your comment I'd need to see what exactly is the definition of surface being used, as that will subtly change why the example I gave fails to be a surface

Comment: FWIW, it's not clear to me from the posted extract whether or not the set of reciprocals _is_ a counterexample according to the author quoted by the OP; the set of reciprocals has $0$ as a limit point, but each _element_ is an isolated point. (By contrast, the set of rationals is certainly a counterexample, since _elements of the set_ are limit points of the set.)

Comment: $S$ can also be finite. And an isolated point is one having some neighborhood which does not contain any other point. Therefore also your second example has only isolated points, but you cannot take the same $\epsilon$ for all points.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang thanks, yes I meant to include 0

Comment: @PaulFrost yes, thanks I've made an edit

Comment: Okay, but in general you cannot take the same $\epsilon$ for all $x \in S$. Consider the set of all $1/n$.

Comment: Has anyone considered this main objection:"I would say that $\mathbf{R}^0$ is a singleton, is that correct ? It should be just the unique map from ∅ to $\mathbf{R}$. So how can a surface in it have more than 1 element ?"

Comment: @user122424 This objection does not occur in your question. And please add the definition of *surface*, without that nobody can give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised that you could not find the definition of "surface" in the book by Lukeš and Malý. The index says that "$k$-dimensional surface" is defined in 34.24. Indeed, on p.150 we can read

[image]

Thus a $0$-dimensional surface is a subspace $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ such that for each $x \in \Omega$ there exists a locally bilipschitz homeomorphic mapping $\varphi$ of an open set $G \subset \mathbb R^0$  ino $\Omega$ such that $x \in \varphi(G)$, and $\varphi(G)$ is a relatively open subset of $\Omega$.
$\mathbb R^0$ is one-point space $*$ which open subsets are $\emptyset$ and $*$. Thus we must have $G = *$ to get $x \in \varphi(G)$. This shows that all single point sets $\{x\}$ are open in $\Omega$, i.e. that $\Omega$ is a discrete subspace of $\mathbb R^n$. Such subspaces are either finite or countably infinite which can be seen as follows:

Since $\Omega$ is discrete, each $x \in \Omega$ has an open neighborhhod $U(x)$ such that $\Omega \cap U(x) =  \{x\}$. There exists $n$ open intervals $(a_i(x),b_i(x))$ with rational endpoints such that $x \in \prod_{i=1}^n (a_i(x),b_i(x)) \subset U(x)$. We then have $\Omega \cap \prod_{i=1}^n (a_i(x),b_i(x))  =\{x\}$. The mapping $x \mapsto \prod_{i=1}^n (a_i(x),b_i(x)) $ is injective: If $\prod_{i=1}^n (a_i(x),b_i(x)) = \prod_{i=1}^n (a_i(y),b_i(y))$, then $\{x\} = \Omega \cap \prod_{i=1}^n (a_i(x),b_i(x)) = \Omega \cap \prod_{i=1}^n (a_i(y),b_i(y)) = \{y\}$, i.e. $x = y$. But there are only countably many boxes $\prod_{i=1}^n (a_i,b_i)$ with rational $a_i,b_i$, therefore $\Omega$ is a countable set.

Answer (score 0):

In your source, $n$ is the same - so there is no $0$-surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$ unless $n=0$, and in this case, as is defined in your text, it's a countable collection of points.

Comment: I don't think that's right, look at the second sentence of section 37.10 which talks of curves in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I would say that $\mathbf{R}^0$ is a singleton, is that correct ? It should be just the unique map from $\emptyset$ to $\mathbf{R}$. So how can a surface in it have more than 1 element ?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^0$ is a singleton, so there is a unique 0-dimensional surface in $\mathbb{R}^0$, however this answer is incorrect, you can have 0-dimensional surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n>0$ which have infinitely many points

Comment: @DavidSheard You are approaching to the core of my question. But look at Derek Allum's answer: $n$ is the **same** so there is no surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$ unless $n=0$.

Comment: Yes, I read the answer, and I believe it is wrong, the text admits the possibility of a $k$-dimensional surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $k<n$. In the image you included it is only in the example of an $n$-dimensional surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $k$ and $n$ match. If you look at the bottom of the page it talks about curves (ie 1-dimensional surfaces) in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which clearly illustrates that $k$ and $n$ need not coincide.

Comment: @DavidSheard That's a pity, I like that answer very much. The problem is in the text itself, the definition is misleading.

Comment: @DavidSheard I think you're right - the fact that they used the same $n$ for the dimension of the surface and the ambient space is a bit odd then. Indeed below they talk about curves in $\mathbb{R}^n$. However, a $0$-surface I still believe is just a countable collection of points, according to this source.